# get special list of result in LDAP search

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am using Ldap in PHP with web front-end. And the result for LDAP search can up to 10k entrys, too big for loading all.

It can any way to get special number record from LDAP Search like get entry number 1000th to 2000th?  Cause when i want see the last 10000th entry, i need load all 10000 entrys

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem, you have 2 questions :

- How to retrieve a big amount of entries
- How to sort the results of a query

For the first problem, you need to use [paged result query](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php)

For the second problem, you need to use the [server-side sort extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891) if these requests are often used. Else you can fetch all the entries you need and sort them [client-side in php](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-sort.php)